# (DiscordJS) How do I detect an emoji?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

So I've just started with discord.js and I have been searching and searching but I just couldn't really find how to detect an emoji. Replying with one works for me, if I make it detect something like 'test', it'll reply with the smirk but after putting different parts of stuff I have seen so far together, I came up with about 3 solutions for detecting an emoji with this being the most "logical" to me. None of them worked... If anyone could help me with this please, that'd be awesome!

```js
const smirk = client.emojis.cache.get("760523853583351818");

if (message.content.toLowerCase() === "test") {
    message.channel.send(`${smirk}`); //this returns "undefined"
}

if (smirk) {
    if (message.content.startsWith("<:smirk:" + smirk.id + ">")) {
        message.channel.send("<:smirk:760523853583351818>");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unicode emojis (the emojis that come global for everyone instead of being custom for servers) are encoded in text content like any other character ("A", "4", "&" or an emoji). They do not use Discord's special bracket notation (if they did, your provided code should probably work. Haven't tested but it looks right).

You can do what you want for this emoji like this:

```
client.on("message", message => {
    if (message.author.bot) return;
    if (message.content.startsWith('')) {
        message.channel.send('');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Ill try it out right away. I got the bracket notation from https://anidiots.guide/coding-guides/using-emojis like I said I tried combining a few solutions since none worked